# Refactoring session check

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, refactoring

I have this repetitive code in all the controllers:

```
        var user = Session["_User"] as User;

        if (user== null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

How can I refactor this? should i add this to an attribute or make a Session Wrapper?

What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

extend your all controllers with a MasterController and override OnActionExecuting method as follows

```
public class MasterController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var user = Session["_User"] as User;

        if (user== null)
        {
            if(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName != "Index" || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName != "ControllerThatContainIndexAction")
            {
                 filterContext.Result = this.RedirectToAction("Index");
                 return;
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: @DarthVader i had updated the code to break the infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

#### Description

There are many ways. I would create a own Controller.
Than you inherit the other controllers from this.

#### Sample

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public User User { get; private set; }

    public BaseController()
    {
        this.User = Session["_User"] as User;
    }
}

public class HomeController: BaseController 
{
    // your action methods
}
```

Comment: if i extend all the other controller from this base controller? why do i still need DI?

Comment: you dont need di but you can use it to set all controller automatically to this. Of course the simpler way is to simple inherit you controller from this class.

Comment: yeah, i dont think DI is any meaningful in this context.

Comment: @DarthVader yes you are right, thats too much. My answer is updated. Thank you!